# How to eliminate incomplete strings?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, keyword, array-formulas

I have a list of keywords, but the program I am using truncates the list at 160 characters, so I am unable to fully see the last keyword string.

I want to use Google Sheets to remove the incomplete parts of the keyword list. This would mean removing the last element altogether, as the picture illustrates.

[image]

I have tried using the trimming function but without much success. How can incomplete strings (any string that contains three dots at the end) be removed from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.*), ")))
```

[image: 0]